# How to run multi applications on the built-in server of play framework 1.2.4?

Tags: playframework, netty

If we want to run the sample application "booking", we need to run this command:

```
play run booking
```

Then you can access this hotel booking application like this: [http://localhost:9000/hotels]

But if you want to run both "yabe" and "booking" samples, I don't know how. While the tomcat can do this, just put them together into the "webapp" folder.

As play official site seems not mentioned this, does anyone know how to run multi applications on the built-in server of play framework(version 1.2.4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to run it on the different ports it can be configured with [application.conf](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/ids)

For live production you need additional use some [frontend HTTP](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production#server) server to allow to co-exists many apps on different ports but working in separate domains on port 80 - see Apache example and `ProxyPass` settings for the vhost section